# Creating a Table with rows of different heights in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to create a Invoice template using reportlab. For the line items in the invoice, I am using a Table. The first row of the table contains the headers and the subsequent rows will be the actual line items. What I basically want to achieve is that if the table contains only 1 line item (plus one row of header), the table should span the entire page.

How can that be done? I don't see any way of specifying the height of the rows individually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the _width_ of each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `TableStyles` and `SPAN` commands.  You can read more about how this works starting on page 81 of the [ReportLab user manual](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf).  This will let you have cells span as many rows and columns as you want.

You can also use `TableStyles` to adjust things like the width and hight of each row and column, but from your description that doesn't sound like what you really wanted to do.

Comment: You cannot set the width and height with `TableStyles`, so I think the second part of your answer is not true

Comment: Technically it's true, however SPAN joins multiple cells into one. It's not a precise solution, if you need an exact number of inches.

Answer (score 14):

You can specify each row heights when creating a Table object :

```
rows = [["Header1", "Header2"], ["Data1", "Data2"]]
table = Table(rows, colWidths=(50*mm, 50*mm), rowHeights=(10*mm, 250*mm))
```

To control text alignment in table cells, you can use TableStyle.